# Loading resources using relative path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application (version 1.5.1.RELEASE) I'm using a third party library which loads resources stored inside the jar file. I have created a fat jar to run this application.

In the library there is this hierarchy of resources which looks like this:

```
com/third/party/package/resources/
\
 \- v1
 |    \ spec_v1.xml
 \- v2
 |    \ spec_v2.xml
 \- v3
 |    \ spec_v3.xml
 |
 \- commons.xml
```

When I use the library I execute that kind of code

```
Resource res = com.third.party.ResourceLoader.load("v1");
```

The v1/spec_v1.xml resource file is loaded and the ResourceLoader class  inspects the content of spec_v1.xml to determine if other there are some other dependency to load. In that case the XML file contains theses lines:

```
<imports>
  <import>../commons.xml</import>
  <!-- other imports -->
<imports>
```

Therefore the loader built a new URL to load the commons.xml resource and this exeception is thrown:

```
com.third.party.ResourceInitializationException: Import failed.  Could not read from URL jar:file:/my_.fat_jarjar!/BOOT-INF/lib/my-dependency-1.2.2.jar!/com/third/party/resources/v1/../commons.xml.
```

According to [that ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7581) it seems to be a feature, not a bug. However I cannot change this library and it worked perfectly before trying to use it with spring boot.

Any idea on how I can workaround that limitation?

Answer (score 2):

For libraries that make assumptions that don't hold true when run from a fat jar, you can [configure Spring Boot's launcher to unpack the library's jar from the executable archive on launch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-extract-specific-libraries-when-an-executable-jar-runs).

If you're using Maven, that would look something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.third.party</groupId>
                        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you're using Gradle, it would look something like this:

```
springBoot  {
    requiresUnpack = ['com.third.party:example']
}
```

Comment: The lib is unpacked at runtime, however the org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection is still used to load the resource and therefore it fails with a FileNotFoundException due to the relative path.

Comment: That's surprising. The jar should have a `file:` URL once it's been extracted from the fat jar. Sounds like a change to the third-party library will be required. Note that I believe it will also fail if you'd used Maven Shade plugin to create an uber jar so this problem isn't specific to Spring Boot.

Comment: Even if the jar is extracted from the fat jar (I verifed that the jar was extracted into a tmp directory), the resource still has a "jar:file" URL and the custom Spring URLHandler which does not support relative path is used.

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help any further without knowing what's going on in the third-party `ResourceLoader` class

Comment: You saved me a lot of trouble.